# Python 3 Beginner - Iterating Triangle

Tags: python, loops, geometry

I am going through a past test and the output of the code is this:

```
Enter the height:
5
     5
    44
   333
  2222
 11111
```

I have to write down the code - so far I know how to make a normal triangle with:

```
 for i in range(5):
 print('*'*i)

 *
 **
 ***
 ****
```

My main question is how do I get the body if the triangle to iterate over the numbers?

So what would the code of the first triangle be? 
Help would be appreciated:)

Comment: _Going through a past test_: You should really take some and try to figure how to do it.

Comment: you're correct - I was being lazy. I'm sorry, will do better next time:)

Comment: also, thank you to everybody for their help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for this is virtually the same, you just need to change the number of times you print each character, and change the `*` that you  are printing to a number.

```
for i in range(5):
    print(str(5-i) * (i+1))
```

This generates:

```
5    
44   
333  
2222 
11111
```

To make it right aligned, like in your example, just use string multiplication on a space character.

```
for i in range(5):
    print(' ' * (4-i) + str(5-i) * (i+1))
```

This will get you:

```
    5
   44
  333
 2222
11111
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use str:

```
for i in range(5):
 print(str(i)*i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Formatted string & spacing with an external array and a negated variable.

```
def height(num):
  rangenum=range(num+1)
  for i in rangenum:
    print(("%"+str(num)+"s")%(i*str(rangenum[-i])))

print("%(spacing as a number)s"%(a string))
```

returns

```
(spacing as a number)-(a string)
```

example:

```
print("%10s"%"this")
```

returns:

```
"      this"
```

side note:

```
%-(a number)s
```

is right justified.

(though python tries to cut down the millions of ways to do the same thing, there still are thousands)

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other answers have been essentially correct, but this one right justifies your triangle like the original output.

```
def print_triangle(rows):
    for i in range(rows + 1):
        print((str(rows + 1-i)*i).rjust(rows))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
height = 5
for i in range(height, 0, -1):
    empty_chars = ' ' * (i - 1)
    filler_chars = str(i) * (height - i + 1)
    print('{}{}'.format(empty_chars, filler_chars))
```